# I'm getting errors for my controller listener in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a password manager flutter application and I'm using Firestore database to store the data(passwords) entered by the users. I have created 4 different text fields on my Flutter application and on the firestore database, namely : title, email, userpassword and url.

I am getting some errors for my listeners.

```
void _titleControllerListener() async {
    final password = _password;
    if (password == null) {
      return;
    }
    final title = _titleController.text;
    await _passwordsService.updatePassword(
      documentId: password.documentId,
      title: title,
    );
  }

  void _emailControllerListener() async {
    final password = _password;
    if (password == null) {
      return;
    }
    final email = _emailController.text;
    await _passwordsService.updatePassword(
      documentId: password.documentId,
      email: email,
    );
  }

  void _userPasswordControllerListener() async {
    final password = _password;
    if (password == null) {
      return;
    }
    final userpassword = _userPasswordController.text;
    await _passwordsService.updatePassword(
      documentId: password.documentId,
      userpassword: userpassword,
    );
  }

  void _urlControllerListener() async {
    final password = _password;
    if (password == null) {
      return;
    }
    final url = _urlController.text;
    await _passwordsService.updatePassword(
      documentId: password.documentId,
      url: url,
    );
  }
```

Errors: These 4 four errors are repeated for a total of 24 errors.

```
The named parameter 'url' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.
The named parameter 'email' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.
The named parameter 'userpassword' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.
The named parameter 'title' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.
```

update password() code(I'm not getting any errors here).

```
Future<void> updatePassword({
    required String documentId,
    required String title,
    required String email,
    required String userpassword,
    required String url,
  }) async {
    try {
      await passwords.doc(documentId).update({titleFieldName: title});
      await passwords.doc(documentId).update({emailFieldName: email});
      await passwords.doc(documentId).update({userpasswordFieldName: userpassword});
      await passwords.doc(documentId).update({urlFieldName: url});
    } catch (e) {
      throw CouldNotUpdatePasswordException();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the errors by splitting the updatePassword() code into 4 different functions. 1 function for each text field.

```
Future<void> updatePasswordTitle({
    required String documentId,
    required String title,
  }) async {
    try {
      await passwords.doc(documentId).update({titleFieldName: title});
    } catch (e) {
      throw CouldNotUpdatePasswordException();
    }
  }

  Future<void> updatePasswordEmail({
    required String documentId,
    required String email,
  }) async {
    try {
      await passwords.doc(documentId).update({emailFieldName: email});
    } catch (e) {
      throw CouldNotUpdatePasswordException();
    }
  }

  Future<void> updatePasswordUserpassword({
    required String documentId,
    required String userpassword,
  }) async {
    try {
      await passwords.doc(documentId).update({userpasswordFieldName: userpassword});
    } catch (e) {
      throw CouldNotUpdatePasswordException();
    }
  }

  Future<void> updatePasswordUrl({
    required String documentId,
    required String url,
  }) async {
    try {
      await passwords.doc(documentId).update({urlFieldName: url});
    } catch (e) {
      throw CouldNotUpdatePasswordException();
    }
  }
```

After creating the above 4 updatePassword functions. I made changes to the controller listeners. So, that they call their own updatePassword function.

```
void _titleControllerListener() async {
    final password = _password;
    if (password == null) {
      return;
    }
    final title = _titleController.text;
    await _passwordsService.updatePasswordTitle(
      documentId: password.documentId,
      title: title,
    );
  }

  void _emailControllerListener() async {
    final password = _password;
    if (password == null) {
      return;
    }
    final email = _emailController.text;
    await _passwordsService.updatePasswordEmail(
      documentId: password.documentId,
      email: email,
    );
  }

  void _userPasswordControllerListener() async {
    final password = _password;
    if (password == null) {
      return;
    }
    final userpassword = _userPasswordController.text;
    await _passwordsService.updatePasswordUserpassword(
      documentId: password.documentId,
      userpassword: userpassword,
    );
  }

  void _urlControllerListener() async {
    final password = _password;
    if (password == null) {
      return;
    }
    final url = _urlController.text;
    await _passwordsService.updatePasswordUrl(
      documentId: password.documentId,
      url: url,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention that when you are calling:

```
await _passwordsService.updatePassword(
      documentId: password.documentId,
      url: url,
    );
```

You are not passing all required parameters. You have various calls to this method and each time you are calling it with different arguments.

I.E.

```
void _userPasswordControllerListener() async {
    final password = _password;
    if (password == null) {
      return;
    }
    final userpassword = _userPasswordController.text;
    await _passwordsService.updatePassword(      //// <----
      documentId: password.documentId,
      userpassword: userpassword,
    );
  }
```

The method updatePassword has five ***required*** arguments:

```
updatePassword({
    required String documentId,   /// <-------
    required String title,        /// <-------
    required String email,        /// <-------
    required String userpassword, /// <-------
    required String url,          /// <-------
   })
```

so you must pass all of them.

An example call could be:

```
await _passwordsService.updatePassword(     
          documentId: password.documentId,
          userpassword: userpassword,
          title: YOUR_TITLE,
          url: YOUR_URL,
          email: YOUR_EMAIL
        );
```

Comment: But I have created and assigned a unique text controller to each text field. So, if I pass all of them won't it give create problems for me ?

Comment: Then you should have created a form that only when all the fields are filled and a submit button is clicked, then you call the updatePassword method. Unless you have a way to get the other fields when calling it from each method.

Comment: Ohh, Could you suggest me any resource from where, I can learn about that ?

Comment: Sure, see [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation). If my answer helped you, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

In `updatePassword` method you specified `title`, `email`, `userpassword` and `url` as required.

You can make them optional:

```
Future<void> updatePassword({
    required String documentId,
    String? title,
    String? email,
    String? userpassword,
    String? url,
  }) async {
    try {
      if (title != null) await passwords.doc(documentId).update({titleFieldName: title});
      if (email != null) await passwords.doc(documentId).update({emailFieldName: email});
      if (userpassword != null) await passwords.doc(documentId).update({userpasswordFieldName: userpassword});
      if (url != null) await passwords.doc(documentId).update({urlFieldName: url});
    } catch (e) {
      throw CouldNotUpdatePasswordException();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now `The parameter 'title' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.`